# React Design Question: Multiple page with same UI layout but different data

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I have been trying to create a news web application. I am stuck in designing my component and need help with it.
There are 3 tabs in my Nav bar which renders the data related to different topics. All these have the same UI layout. So currently I have created 3 different pages but they all call the same Child component with different props.  In the child component depending on the props provided HTTP call is made to fetch the data.

They share the same stateful component.

Is this the right way to develop it. Or they should be making http calls in their own  respective component?

Comment: Sounds like you have a use case for a generic page container that should be able to call an API, possibly as a target URL or  API param that is passed as a prop. Can you update your question to include an actual code example for what you are trying, and details about any issues/concerns? As-is your question is a little to open-ended, which tends to attract opinionated answers and comments.

Comment: That being said, your approach seems logical to me.